# What are different between peers and remote in ethereum wallet?

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp

I run ethereum wallet on my Windows 10 PC, sometimes it displays "1 peers", and sometimes it display "remote", would you please see the image?

What are different between peers and remote in ethereum wallet?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shows the number of peers when the node your Mist connects to is fully synchronized, and it shows `Remote` when the synchronization is not fully done.

This is confirmed by [the code responsible](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/blob/c620110dfaddd7e7526c82a8fcd603ded73c86e1/interface/components/NodeInfo/index.js#L199) for displaying that.